# SQL Server : pivot on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Hmm, only getting the correct title took me 10 minutes and I'm not sure I got it covering my question. Some background info: my table contains backup results from multiple servers. For simplicity some rows for just one server:

```
hostname    type_id result_id   received
----------------------------------------
SBS2011       5        1      2016-06-28
SBS2011       5        1      2016-06-28
SBS2011       5        1      2016-06-29
SBS2011       5        1      2016-06-29
SBS2011       5        1      2016-06-30
SBS2011       6        1      2016-06-30
SBS2011       5        2      2016-07-01
SBS2011       6        2      2016-07-01
SBS2011       6        2      2016-07-01
SBS2011       5        1      2016-07-02
SBS2011       6        1      2016-07-02
SBS2011       5        1      2016-07-03
SBS2011       6        1      2016-07-03
SBS2011       5        1      2016-07-04
SBS2011       6        1      2016-07-04
```

Using a PIVOT I can get an overview of the amount of backups for each weekday:

```
select * from 
(
    select [hostname], [type_id], datepart(w, received) as workday from [backups]
) TEMP
pivot (
    count([type_id])
    for workday in
    ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) as pvt;
```

Results in:

```
hostname    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
--------------------------------------
SBS2011     2   2   2   2   2   3   2
```

But this result misses some crucial info. As result_id equals 'success' and result_id equals 'failed', I would like to have the result to look like this:

```
hostname    1:1 1:2 2:1 2:2 3:1 3:2 4:1 4:2 5:1 5:2 6:1 6:2 7:1 7:2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SBS2011     2   0   2   0   2   0   2   0   2   0   0   3   2   0
```

where columnname 1:1 is shorthand for sunday:success and 1:2 equals sunday:failed. For some backup type_id's, there may be also a column 1:3 for sunday:retry.

As I looked around, I found that a DYNAMIC PIVOT may be the key in solving this puzzle. Others suggest a PARTITION BY, but I have not yet found out how. The DYNAMIC PIVOT seems the most promising, but I do not know how. Please help me create this - for me complex - query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to fiddle with dynamic SQL you could just keep it static and alter the column that is pivoted on.

A query like:

```
select * 
from 
(
    select 
        [hostname], 
        [type_id], 
        concat(datepart(w, received),':',result_id) as workday 
    from [backups]
) TEMP
pivot (
    count([type_id])
    for workday in (
        -- maybe you don't want the :3 option for all days? Adjust as needed
        [1:1],[1:2],[1:3], 
        [2:1],[2:2],[2:3], 
        [3:1],[3:2],[3:3], 
        [4:1],[4:2],[4:3], 
        [5:1],[5:2],[5:3], 
        [6:1],[6:2],[6:3], 
        [7:1],[7:2],[7:3]
    )
) as pvt;
```

might give a result similar to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and see if it solves your issue... pretty sure I can simplify this further but need to know what the decodes are for type_id ( 5 and 6  ). will there be more type_id's ?

Also  result_id = 1 = Success and 2 = Failure right ?

Question what happens when the backup is not run at all on a particular day :) ? how do you handle that situation as there will be no records for that day. :)

```
/* Create table and populate with sample data.
create table Backups (hostname varchar(10),    type_id int , result_id int ,  received datetime)

insert into Backups (hostname ,   type_id ,result_id ,  received ) values 
('SBS2011',       5  ,      1      ,'2016-06-28'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     1      ,'2016-06-28'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     1      ,'2016-06-29'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     1      ,'2016-06-29'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     1      ,'2016-06-30'),
('SBS2011',       6   ,     1      ,'2016-06-30'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     2      ,'2016-07-01'),
('SBS2011',       6   ,     2      ,'2016-07-01'),
('SBS2011',       6   ,     2      ,'2016-07-01'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     1      ,'2016-07-02'),
('SBS2011',       6   ,     1      ,'2016-07-02'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     1      ,'2016-07-03'),
('SBS2011',       6   ,     1      ,'2016-07-03'),
('SBS2011',       5   ,     1      ,'2016-07-04'),
('SBS2011',       6   ,     1      ,'2016-07-04')

select * , DatePart(w, received) from dbo.Backups b  

*/
```

**The Query:**

```
SELECT -- S.*, F.* 
        S.[hostname],
        S.[1] as [1:1],
        F.[1] as [1:2],
        S.[2] as [2:1],
        F.[2] as [2:2],
        S.[3] as [3:1],
        F.[3] as [3:2],
        S.[4] as [4:1],
        F.[4] as [4:2],
        S.[5] as [5:1],
        F.[5] as [5:2],
        S.[6] as [6:1],
        F.[6] as [6:2],
        S.[7] as [7:1],
        F.[7] as [7:2]

FROM
(
    select * from 
    (
        select [hostname], [type_id], datepart(w, received) as workday , result_id as res_type from [backups] where result_id = 1

    ) TEMP
    pivot 
    (
        count([type_id]) 
        for workday in
        ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
    ) as pvt

) S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    select * from 
    (
        select [hostname], [type_id], datepart(w, received) as workday , result_id as res_type from [backups] where result_id = 2

    ) TEMP
    pivot 
    (
        count([type_id]) 
        for workday in
        ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
    ) as pvt

) F ON S.res_type = F.res_type - 1
WHERE F.hostname IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Yes, type_id's 1 to 4 are also present depending on the host. There are also more then these two result_id's, but that should not be too hard to extend. Backups which failed to run is indeed another question and another query. For now I will stick to the sum of the different type_id's. If the sum is less then the other days, something went wrong.

Comment: Type_id's represent the source software and backup type. Type_id = 1 for example equals Acronis VMprotect, type_id = 2 equals Acronis VMprotect Dual Destination, type_id = 3 equals Symantec BackupExec, etc